# NUnit tests for net core WebAPI applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, nunit

I recently started programming in net. I have the following question: I have a web application with a database, the data level and the business logic level are written, how to write nunit tests for the business logic level, I found on the Internet that you can use moq( mock), but I do not understand at all how. The database is accessed via DbContext. Link to the project:(https://github.com/Aleksandr34nov/WebApiApp), I'll add something here. Here I tried to write a test:

```
namespace BuissnessLayerTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    class SongTests
    {
        private static DbContextOptions<ASContext> options;
        private static ASContext context = new ASContext(options);
        private static EFSongsRepository _songRep = new EFSongsRepository(new SongDataAccess(context));
        [Test]
        public void GetItemByIdTest()
        {
            Song song = new Song();
            song.SongTitle = "In The End";
            song.AlbumId = -1;
            int id = _songRep.AddItem(song);
            Song? testSong = _songRep.GetItemById(id);
            _songRep.DeleteItem(song);
            if (song.Equals(testSong))
            {
                Assert.Pass();
            }else 
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Got mistake:**
[Mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3NTF.png)

I don't fully understand how it all works, please tell me how to write tests correctly. **Here is the project structure:**
[Struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX7MQ.png)

**There are entityes(Song and Album):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Domain
{
    public class Song
    {
        public int SongId { get; set; }
        public string SongTitle { get; set; }
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public Album Album { get; set; }
        public Song() { }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Domain
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public List<Song> SongList { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        public Album() { }
    }
}
```

**This is context:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Domain;

namespace DataLayer
{
    public class ASContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }

        public ASContext(DbContextOptions<ASContext> options) : base(options) { }
    }

    public class EFDBContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ASContext>
    {
        public ASContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ASContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AlbumsSongsDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DataLayer"));

            return new ASContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make out from your code you appear to be testing at the wrong level. If you are using a repository pattern, that serves as the outer boundary of your code under test. Your API controllers, or services are the gate keepers of business logic, and what unit tests would cover. The Repository pattern serves as an abstraction for data, and is what you would Mock.

Repositories either deal with returning one of three things:

- Concrete entities (`TEntity` / `IEnumerable<TEntity>`)
- DTOs
- `IQueryable<TEntity>`

You test Repositories with integration tests wired up to a real, known-state database or in-memory database. (No mocking involved) You unit test your controllers etc. by mocking the repository so that it merely returns a known state, essentially based on a populated entity or list of entities suited for the scenario you are testing.  It is possible to mock the DbContext and DbSets, but frankly it's quite messy and avoiding that complexity is entirely the point of adopting a repository pattern.